# fopen64 compile error under XCode with Cocos2D-X

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x

I try to setup a new XCode Project for Cocos2D-x by myself, but I get an odd compile error in file cocos2dx/support/zip_support/ioapi.cpp, and XCode complains about the code using fopen64, ftello64 etc. My question is that is there any setting I need to set in order to make XCode compiled with these 64 bit functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can `#define USE_FILE32API`, preferably in your project settings. This is caused by the new version of [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) with 64-bit support.